# Stored procedure: conditional code when parameter value changes from record value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

What I am trying to do is to create a stored procedure `UpdatePrice` that takes two parameters `(@PartId, @Price)` and checks to see if the price given is equal to the current price and if not then nothing happens.

If it is different, then I insert a new row into a table called `PriceHistory` detailing these changes. The part I am having trouble with is checking for equivalence.

My inclination was to say

```
begin transaction PriceUpdate
    if @Price = Price 
    begin
        --
    end 
    else begin 
        insert into PriceHistory(@PartId, ChangeDate, PreviousPrice, NewPrice)
            select @PartId, GetDate(), p.Price, @Price
            from Part p
            where PartID = @PartId
    end
```

However the problem is that `Price` is obviously not something valid I can put there. So how would I go about getting the current price for the given `PartId`?

Comment: Price will always be set via this stored procedure? No one writing a one-off ever to mass update data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `exists` statement to check whether the record exists with the expected conditions e.g. Price the same or difference, and then execute conditional code.

```
begin tran
  if exists (select 1 from dbo.Part where PartId = @PartId and coalesce(Price,0) <> coalesce(@Price,0)) begin
    -- Further statements here for when price is equal
  end else begin
    -- Further statements here for when price is not equal
    insert into PriceHistory(@PartId, ChangeDate, PreviousPrice, NewPrice)
      select @PartId, GetDate(), p.Price, @Price
      from Part p
      where PartID = @PartId
  end
commit
```

Comment: I do have further statements. After I've checked whether they are different or not, I have to insert a row into my PriceHistory table with a few items. So how would I do it without using coalesce? (btw thank you for showing me that coalesce is a thing, I did not know about that prior to this)

Comment: Ok I realized the problem in my explanation in my original post and have updated it to more accurately reflect my situation. I think I was misunderstanding what coalesce was doing so disregard that comment. Sorry for the confusion. The problem with your solution is I was wrong about updating the price, I am not actually updating it, I am just checking for equivalence and then executing further statements based on whether there is a difference in the old and new price or not

Comment: Ok I think that's closer to what I was trying to do. May I ask why you have 'select 1'? Is that selecting the first row brought up when PartId = @PartId?

Comment: Its an `exists statement` - you don't need any data from the select, you are just testing that a row meeting the where clause criteria exists. You can put anything you like there and it won't make any difference e.g. `select 1`, `select *`, `select PartID`

Comment: oh ok I understand now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Actually I do have a question regarding the coalesce statement.... why do you need the '0' after price? What I have read about coalesce says you can choose any number of parameters to pass to it so couldn't you just pass it @Price and leave it at that?

Comment: You could use `coalesce` that way, but what if accidentally `@Price` comes in as null? Its just defensive programming i.e. assuming the worst case. Because you can't compare null values using `=` you have to use ` is ` so its easier to remove the `null` and compare a value.

Comment: Ok so if I am understanding right then the reason for the zero is that if @Price is null then coalesce will just pass zero as the value?

Comment: Correct - you can change that to anything that suits, e.g. `-1` or `-999`. Thats totally up to how your business logic wants to deal with 1 or both values being null. Which probably isn't supposed to happen, but we all know it could at some point. You might choose to have a totally separate code branch for when 1 or both is null and to reject the update and notify someone. As I say, thats for your business logic to decide.

Comment: Ok it is very clear now. Thanks so much for your help, I have learned a lot from this